# Preloading imported fonts in Vue3/Vite/Rollup

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, webfonts, rollupjs, preload

How do I preload a font imported from an npm package in a Vue3 (vite/rollup) application?

eg: I've referenced the material font library:

```
npm install --save material-symbols
```

and imported it in main.js:

```
import 'material-symbols';
```

The font works fine except for the FOUT flicker when the page loads so I'd like to preload it, but how do I get the URL for the asset and get it into the document head?

Things I've found:

- The Vite docs mention [how to get the URL of an imported asset](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html) but that only works from js.  How do I get the URL into the document head?
- [This page](https://thewebdev.info/2022/03/10/how-to-reference-static-assets-with-vue-js) talks about referencing static assets with `@/` syntax but that only works in vue templates - again, not in the document head
- I can't just guess the final asset name because after packaging it ends up something like "/assets/material-symbols-outlined.a9af8db1.woff2"

---

Follow up: I didn't end up finding a good solution for this but ended up doing the following:

1. Switched to a smaller version of the material symbol font with just the one weight. (2Mb down to 200K).
2. Wrote a small post-processing bash script (see below) to work out the target filename and used sed to patch the preload link into the packaged index.html body head.

Also, I'm thinking of switching from using ligatures to unicode html entities for each symbol.  The ligatures are quite long before the font loads causing the layout to be dramatically wrong until the font has loaded.  eg: before loading the ligature text is something like "settings" which then reduces to a single symbol character.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Find name of the asset file
newfile=$(basename `ls dist/assets/material-symbols-outlined*`)

# Insert into head
mv dist/index.html dist/index.orig.html
expr='s/(<title>)/<link rel="preload" crossorigin href="\/assets\/'$newfile'" as="font">\n    \1/'
sed -r "$expr" dist/index.orig.html > dist/index.html
```

Comment: Do you use SSR or just the client side rendering?

Comment: Just client side rendering, no SSR

Comment: If you just use CSR so you need to put your font files into the `public` folder and add the link directly to the `index.html` file. Because if you use JS to add the preload link in the client, the link will be added after the JS is loaded and run. It is way too late and makes no sense in terms of preloading

Comment: I realise that but as mentioned in the original post the font file is packaged to the assets folder. I guess what I’m after is some way to inject the final font url into the index.html head area.

Answer (score 0):

For **Laravel** with **Vite plugin**, you can achieve the above by using the `Vite::asset()` [helper](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite#working-with-blade-and-routes) in your blade template. Eg.:

```
<link rel="preload" href="{{ Vite::asset('resources/fonts/icofont.woff2') }}" as="font" />
```

This will use correct temporary URL when in `npm run dev`, and will be replaced by proper asset URL including the version suffix hash on `npm run build`.